# Executing Custom Fields in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using a custom sidebar in a Wordpress web site, however the default sidebar is displayed on my post page, not the custom sidebar. I had this working on a different site this time last year, could it be a problem with Wordpress 3.8.1 ?? Below is the code for the custom side bar that should act as a custom field in the post page.

```
<?php $sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebar", true);
get_sidebar($sidebar);
?>
```

Any ideas guys? Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you inserting this code?

Comment: It's not 3.8.1, the template hierarchy is the same.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: I am inserting the code in my single.php, replacing the original sidebar code with my own @Dynelight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can't find the template......ensure the value in the postmeta corresponds to sidebar-file name in the theme. e.g. if your meta value is "file" it will look for sidebar-file.

Comment: In my post I have selected the Custom field templet as 'Sidebar' and the value as 'post-01' aka 'name of file'. @David

Comment: so you have a file called sidebar-post-01.php in your theme?

Comment: no, I have a file called post-01.php in my theme, I am selecting sidebar as a Value in the Custom fields.

Comment: all the same rename it to sidebar-post-01.php ...it should work then, all you're doing with add_meta is saving the name which the get_sidebar function translates to "look for template called sidebar-xxx.php" the same as single-custom-post.php for custom post templates, etc.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Whats annoying is, is that I had this working this time last year! I'll go through the stages with you to make sure i'm doing this right. 

Replace get_sidebar in single.php with above code
Duplicate sidebar.php
Rename it sidebar-01.php
Upload it to my theme
In the Post, select ‘Sidebar’ as my Custom Field Name 
In the Post, type ‘sidebar-01.php’ and my Custom Field Value

Can you spot any anomalies @Dave

Thanks for all your help, really appreciate it

Comment: dont worry about it, simple things can wreck your head!, just type "01" in the post_meta, if you save sidebar-01 in the post_meta, it will look for sidebar-sidebar01.php....as a quick check do get_sidebar('01'), btw saving this as an integer may cause difficulty, i havent looked at get_sidebar() but it may just look for a string "===" rather than either value "==", if the get_sidebar('01') dosent work try calling it something else, just to be sure!

Comment: YOU GOT IT! Thats the one :) thanks so much @Dave really appreciate all the help and time put in!